# Make spacing independent of other elements (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I have a logo on the far left. There is a div container in the middle and a div container on the far left. All packed together in a div container.

I have the middle container on `margin: auto;` adjusted so that it has the same distance on both sides.

The problem is that if I move the logo left or right, the middle container also moves. How can I ensure that the middle container always stays in the middle no matter what happens left or right?

```css
body {
  margin: 0%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.container1 {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #e7e0e0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.container12 {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.container12 h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.container13 {
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.container13 a {
  margin: 0%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  float: inline-start;
}

.container13 a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.trennlinie {
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-right: 12.5px;
}

.trennliniehilfe {
  padding-left: 12.5px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.container2 {
  height: 80px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(187, 187, 187);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.airbnblogo {
  width: 50px;
}

.airbnbcont {
  margin-left: 110px;
  ;
}

.mittecontainer {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  float: inline-start;
  background-color: rgb(214, 212, 212);
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.mittecontainer p {
  margin-left: 11.5px;
}

.part3 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 35px;
}

.derretter {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.interneticon {
  margin-right: 15px;
  width: 30px;
}

.Pics img {
  width: 250px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.Pics {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 80px;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.p1 {
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
  padding-right: 12.5px;
}

.p2 {
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
  padding-right: 12.5px;
}

.Pics p {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.pics2 {
  background-color: black;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.pics2 p {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.pics2 p:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

.ia {
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Airbnb.com</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="container12">
      <h1>Hier kommt das Airbnb 2022: Winter-Update</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container13">
      <a class="trennlinie" href="">Film abspielen</a>
      <a class="trennliniehilfe" href="">Alle Neuigkeiten entdecken</a>
    </div>

  </div>


  <div class="container2">
    <div class="airbnbcont">
      <img class="airbnblogo" src="airbnb.png">
    </div>

    <div class="mittecontainer">
      <p class="p1">Irgendwo</p>
      <p class="p2">Eine Woche</p>
      <p>Gäste hinzufügen</p>
    </div>

    <div class="part3">

      <div class="derretter">
        <p>Als Gastgeber:in loslegen</p>
      </div>

      <div class="interneticon">
        <img class="ia" src="internet.png" alt="">

      </div>

      <div>
        <img class="ia" src="menu.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="Pics">
    <div class="pics2">
      <img src="din1.jpg"> <br>
      <p>Jetzt Flug sichern!</p>
      <p>Weitere Infos</p>
      <p>Standort</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Be sure to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of just dumping all of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `container2` class in the style tag, replace `display: flex;` to be `display: grid;` and add `grid-template-columns: 25% 50% 25%;`. Like this:

```css
.container2 {
  height: 80px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(187, 187, 187);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 50% 25%;
  align-items: center;
}
```

And don't forget if there are too many CSS styles, then make an external CSS link so that giving css styles is easier.